# Excel Conditional Formatting based on 4 cells?

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to conditionally format a workbook to highlight an entire row if there are text values in four columns.

For example, if the row has an "x" in columns E to H, I want that row to be green. If there is a blank in columns E to H, I want that row to be red.

At the minute, I am using `=IF($E1:$H1="x", TRUE)` to format to green, and `=IF($E1:$H1="x", FALSE)` to format to red. However, even though I apply this to the entire workbook, the formatting only seems to take place when the text in column E is effected. If I create a blank in columns F, G and H, the row remains green.

I have also tried using `=ISBLANK($E1:$H1)` to format rows to red. However, once again, if there is an "x" in `$E1`, the whole cell is formatted green.

I have the conditional formatting applying to `$A:$H` as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you're using an array formula and will be working only if E1 contains `x` in the first case or is blank in the second case.

Try using this formula instead:

```
=IF(COUNTA($E1:$H1)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

To highlight the row if cells E1 to H1 contains at least one text.

EDIT: Try using

```
=COUNTA($E1:$H1)=4
```

(meaning all three cells are filled with something). If you want to specifically count the x, use:

```
=COUNTIF($E1:$H1,"x")=4
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this formula still doesn't do what I am aiming for.

Let me try to clarify what I am aiming to achieve. I am using columns E:H as tick boxes in effect. By putting an "x" in E, F, G and H, I want the row to turn green, but **only if an "x" is present in all four columns.** If an "x" is missing from *any* column, I want that row to be red.

Comment: @RachelBrown Oops, I'm not sure why I didn't get any notification of your comment. Understood: try using `=IF(COUNTA($E1:$H1)=4,TRUE,FALSE)` (meaning all three cells are filled with something). If you want to specifically count the `x`, use: `=IF(COUNTIF($E1:$H1,"x")=4,TRUE,FALSE)`. Let me know how it goes!